# Does non-ECC RAM work in a ECC motherboard?

Tags: memory, ecc

I have HP Workstation xw4600 ([datasheet](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/pscmisc/vac/us/product_pdfs/xw4600_datasheet_may09_043009.pdf)) with two ECC RAM modules in it. I want buy more RAM modules, specifically two regular non-ECC DDR2 800 MHz. Will these non-ECC RAMs work with this ECC motherboard? If yes, will they work together with the two ECC RAMs or I can use only one type? Thanks.

Comment: Depends on if your able to disable the ECC feature within the firmware.  It's very unlikely if your unable to do that the system will boot and if it does it might be unstable.

Answer (score 3):

[Manual](http://h50146.www5.hp.com/lib/doc/manual/workstation/hp_workstation/WS_UG_xw4600_STRG_453080-001_screen.pdf) for xw4600 only lists unbuffered PC2–5300E (667 MHz) and PC2–6400E (800 MHz) DIMMs being supported:

> Use only industry-standard, unbuffered, PC2–5300E (667 MHz) or PC2–6400E (800 MHz) DIMMs.
>
> If multiple DIMMs are installed in a workstation, they must be installed in pairs of the same size and typein each channel.

Comment: You should quote (screenshot) the relevant information from the manual